# Mongoose Pagination - Limit to 1 on first query then limit to 10 on succeeding queries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a problem regarding pagination of my comments.

I have seen and tried several answers here but it doesn't solve my problem:

**Scenario**
On my first query on my axios, I wanted only to query `1 comment`. I have this example query params:
And this successfully gives me a 1 comment

```
  // limit = 1 
  // offset = 0
  http://localhost:9000/api/v1/comment/someID?offset=0&limit=1
 
  // result = [ { ... } ]
```

**Problem**
On my second query I wanted the rest of my query to limit the comments to `10`
Now problem is, what if I only have `5` comments?
Now the value of  `skip = 1 * 10`. How do I set the value of `skip` so that it will only skip the `1 comment` I queried first ?

```
  // limit = 10    Previous limit is = 1
  // offset = 1    Previous offset = 0
  http://localhost:9000/api/v1/comment/someID?offset=1&limit=10

 // result = []
```

I get an empty array because it had skipped `10 documents` while I only have `5 documents`

In my server file, this is how I handle the pagination:

```
const offset = parseInt(req.query.offset) || 0;
const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 10;
const skip = offset * limit;

const comments = await Comment
     .find({ _post_id: post_id })
     .populate({
        path: 'author',
        select: 'fullname username profilePicture'
     })
     .limit(limit)
     .skip(skip)
     .sort({ createdAt: -1 });

res.status(200).send(comments)
```

What is the best approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: add third parameter to server and call it skip. if you pass 'skip' then  server use it if not then skip become offset * limit. Simplest idea that i get it to just make more control over esult.

Comment: @Robert You saved my life. Thanks for the idea! Now I'm using this: ```const skip = parseInt(req.query.skip) || offset * limit;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple problem with simple solution.
Thanks to [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12466239/robert) for solving the problem:

In my route, I set the value of `skip` to use the value of `req.query.skip` if it exist else use the `offset * limit` as value of skip.

```
    const skip = parseInt(req.query.skip) || offset * limit;
```